# Find Pivot Index

Tags: java, arrays, loops, indexing, data-structures

I can't understand why second loop is in this. Like first loop is to enter the elements from array. What's the purpose of second array. And when I'm dry running it, it's giving me o/p as "2".

```
class Solution {
    public int pivotIndex(int[] nums) {
        int ls = 0;
        int rs = 0;
        int PI = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            PI+=nums[i];
        }
        rs = PI;
        for(int i =0; i<nums.length; i++) {
            ls+=nums[i];
            if(ls==rs)
                return i;
            rs-=nums[i];
        }      
        return -1;          
    }
}
```

Comment: What input do you provide to have it output `2`? What is a pivot? Is the code doing what it's supposed to do, or is there a bug? It looks like `PI` is a sum of the entire array, `ls` is the sum of everything to the left of `i`, and `rs` is the sum of everything to the right of `i` (both including the element at `i` itself). So, this method appears to return the position in the array where the sum of the elements to its left and right (inclusive) are equal. Is that what you're expecting? Please provide more details about the problem and about how you've been debugging it.

Comment: From what I understand, the problem is to find an index (if present)  such that the sum of values upto that pivot index is equal to the sum of values after it. 
The first loop find the sum of all items in the input and keep it as rs, probably short for right sum. And the left sum is zero. And the second loop gradually go through the input to look for a point where left sum is equal to right sum. But this is all guess work, it would be a lot nice if the question is more clear.

Comment: The question is that we've to find a pivot index where sum of element present on its left is equal to sum of elements on its right. I can figure out that it'll be solved like Quick Sort method. But what's the purpose of another loop?